# Create custom social share icons which share current page url

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend, socialsharing-plugin

I am trying to develop an widget which has social sharing buttons when clicked should share the current page'e url to respective social media website. For e.g, I tried to embed twitter share button referring from [here](https://publish.twitter.com/?buttonType=TweetButton&widget=Button) and pasted the following code inside my html:

```
   <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button"  data-url="https://www.google.com" data-show-count="false"></a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
```

but I don't want my button to look that way, I modified the styles for the button by changing the class name of  tag, appearance changed but the button is not working the it's supposed to work. It opens a twitter page as following:

[image]

I want to retain the functionality of the twitter share icon but also change the style of the button.While clicking share, it should look something like:

[image]

Comment: Using javascripts `window.open()` you can set window dimensions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: okay, lets say I open window , but how do I share the content as in image2 ? opening a window in new tab just looks like image1. I want it be similar to the second image.

Comment: Then you need to specify that link: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo

Answer (score 0):

Twitters url accepts many parameters, that change how share page looks like:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=demo
    &original_referer=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.twitter.com%2Fen%2Fdocs%2Ftwitter-for-websites%2Ftweet-button%2Foverview
    &ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw
    &related=twitterapi%2Ctwitter
    &text=Hello%20world
    &tw_p=tweetbutton
    &url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo
    &via=twitterdev
```

Looks like you want to use `url` parameter.

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo
```

From https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview